# OSX directory with spaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-io, directory

I'm having an issue with opening directories that have spaces in them.  My code looks like this:

```
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
{

    NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];

        NSString* directoryName = [[files objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString];
    directoryURL = [files objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Directory Name: %@", directoryName);


        NSArray *directoryArray = [directoryName componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];


    NSString* currentDirectory = [directoryArray objectAtIndex:(directoryArray.count- 2)];

    [directoryBox setTitle:currentDirectory];
}
```

When I select a directory name with spaces the files are not displayed in a table and the output in the NSLog looks like this:

Directory Name:

```
file://localhost/Users/Rich/Software%20Bisque/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`-URLs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenPanel/URLs) method of of `NSOpenPanel` returns instances of `NSURL`, not file system paths. While `NSURL`s have become the preferred way to refer to files, you can easily change to a file system path by using `NSURL`'s [`-path`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) method.

Note that there are many methods specific to working with file system paths that are added to `NSString` in `NSPathUtilities.h`. You could probably rewrite your code to incorporate those (double-check that I've got your targeted directory okay):

```
NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];

NSString* directoryName = [[files objectAtIndex:0] path];
directoryURL = [files objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Directory Name: %@", directoryName);

// NSArray *directoryArray = [directoryName pathComponents];

// NSString* currentDirectory = [directoryArray objectAtIndex:(directoryArray.count- 2)];

NSString *currentDirectory = [[directoryName stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                    lastPathComponent];

[directoryBox setTitle:currentDirectory];
```

Comment: Was this more of a push in the right direction or should it be working as is?  Unfortunately I'm still seeing Directory Name: file://localhost/Users/Rich/Software%20Bisque/  And the directoryBox Title is set to Rich. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the percent escapes in the `directoryName` string - I don't think the system needs them there. Something like:

```
directoryName = [directoryName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```